# change the display of a row in a table react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started working on react recently. In my code I have a table component and i have multiple pages. So whenever I need to show data in table, I use the same table component. Now in a certain page, when I delete a row, I want to change the color of that row only/ change the background color that row. In other pages, I don't have any deleting option.

For displaying data, I am using DetailList from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib". Can anyone help me, how could I solve my problem? should I use onRenderRow? how?

Comment: The tiger ate my goat's grass. Where is the tiger now? It's something like that. Your question is very unclear. Add some relevant code for us so that we may help you.

Comment: You can use HOC to abstract your code by sharing the same part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

**In your specific page:**

```
changeBackgroundColor(event){
  // do sth with the clicked row
}

<YourTableComponent click={(event) => this.changeBackgroundColor(event)} />
```

**In your Component:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onClick={this.props.click}>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```